# Scraping data from website using Beautiful Soup and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a python script that use the BeautifulSoup and Pandas packages in order to  **scrape** data from a list of urls and convert the data into a dataframe then save it as excel file and  send it by email  as attachment.

**The problem is that when the script run and finish the scraping of the first item  it crash and return the error below:**

```
ValueError: 15 columns passed, passed data had 14 columns
```

I think this means that there is a missing **html tag** right??

The list includes 3 urls.

code:

```
import time
from datetime import date
import smtplib

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.utils import formatdate

def scrape_website():
    url_list = ["https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/",
                "https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/head-chef-jobs/",
                "https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-sous-chef-jobs/"]
    for url in url_list:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

        links = []
        for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
            if a['href'] not in links:
                links.append("https://www.bayt.com" + a['href'])
        joineddd = []

        for link in links:
            s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
            alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select(
                "div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
            alldd.insert(0, link)
            joineddd.append(alldd)
        print("Web Crawling is Done for  {}".format(url))
        convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd)
    send_email()

def remove_unwanted_cols(dataset, cols):
    for col in cols:
        del dataset[col]
    return dataset

def convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd):
    df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd, columns=[
        "link", "location", "Company_Industry", "Company_Type",
        "Job_Role", "Employment_Type", "Monthly_Salary_Range",
        "Number_of_Vacancies", "Career_Level",
        "Years_of_Experience", "Residence_Location",
        "Gender","Nationality","Degree","Age"])
    df = remove_unwanted_cols(df, ["Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Number_of_Vacancies"])
    df_to_excel = df.to_excel(r"F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx", index = False, header=True)
    send_email()

def send_email():
    '''send email '''
    today = date.today()
    file = 'F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx'
    username='XXXXXXXXXXX'
    password='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    send_from = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    send_to = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    Cc = 'recipient'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Cc'] = Cc
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, This is a test mail {}'.format(today)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    port = '587'
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'vnd.ms-excel')
    part.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='jobs Description--{}'.format(today))
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username, password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to.split(',') + msg['Cc'].split(','), msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrape_website()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update func `scrape_website()`, save alldd as dictionary.

```
for link in links:
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml") 
    ### update Start ###
    alldd = dict()
    alldd['link'] = link
    dd_div = [i for i in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] div") 
              if ('<dd>' in str(i) ) and ( "<dt>" in str(i))]
    for div in dd_div:
        k = div.select_one('dt').get_text(';', True)
        v = div.select_one('dd').get_text(';', True)
        alldd[k] = v
    ### update End  ###    
    joineddd.append(alldd)


# result
df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd)
```

alladd sample:

```
{
         'link': 'https://www.bayt.com/en/qatar/jobs/executive-chef-4298309/',       
         'Job Location': 'Doha, Qatar',
         'Company Industry': 'Real Estate; Hospitality & Accomodation; Catering, Food Service, & Restaurant',
         'Company Type': 'Employer (Private Sector)',
         'Job Role': 'Hospitality and Tourism',
         'Employment Type': 'Unspecified',
         'Monthly Salary Range': 'Unspecified',
         'Number of Vacancies': 'Unspecified',
         'Career Level': 'Mid Career',
         'Years of Experience': 'Min: 7',
         'Residence Location': 'Qatar',
         'Degree': "Bachelor's degree / higher diploma"
}
```

Comment: one more word, it is better to save the data per request, or when you encounter an exception, you will lose your previous work in `scrap_website` function.

Comment: That said, def functions to crawl the links web and detail web separately.

Comment: i tried your answer it return in the dataframe the data of the last item in the url list
`https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-sous-chef-jobs/`
it does not save the previous scraped data  so how to add the new scraped data to the existing data of the first 2 items of the url list ??

Comment: move `joineddd = []` before  `for url in url_list:`

Comment: how to remove unwanted columns ??? because in your answer it scrap all the data but i need to delete some fields

Comment: use `cols=['A', 'B']; df[cols]`, as cols is the columns you wanted.

Comment: i tried your comment like this :
`cols = ["link","location","Job_Role","Employment_Type","Monthly_Salary_Range","Career_Level",
                "Years_of_Experience","Residence_Location","Gender","Nationality","Degree"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd,cols)`

but the script crash and display the below error :
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20, 15), indices imply (11, 15)`

Comment: sounds like you are not familiar with pandas, the cols element should be in `df.columns`.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: i did add the columns as you suggested but now it return  data into 3 columns only  as :
`link, gender, degree` only.

`cols = ["link","location","Company_Industry","Company_Type",                "Job_Role","Employment_Type","Monthly_Salary_Range","Number_of_Vacancies","Career_Level",             "Years_of_Experience","Residence_Location","Gender","Nationality","Degree"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd,columns = cols)`

Comment: Then check if the web content is parsed correctly,  change `dd_div = [i for i in s.select("div.card-content div")  if ('<dd>' in str(i) ) and ( "<dt>" in str(i))]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: 15 columns passed, passed data had 14 columns
```

What I read here means that you designated the dataframe to have 15 columns, but the data that you feed it only has 14 features. You need to check your original file to make sure it actually has the data you expect, or adjust your expected columns and their names to match the file.

Comment: that is the problem where the first item in the url list  contains 15 data that is why i have a dataframe that contains 15 columns    where as the second item it contains 14 data 
my question is how to deal with this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. Options can be: drop the excessive column from your first batch; create an empty column for consequent batches to make them consistent with the first batch; keep and treat the first and consequent batches differently. You can also create a dataframe right where you are making the array, and concat further dataframes to the first one, and they will adjust.

Comment: so let say i want to make all the batches consequent so i will create an empty column how to do it in the script ?

Comment: Right now we don't even see what you have in the list that you are using to make the dataframe. There are several paths you can take as I mentioned in the previous comment, you may want to explore those paths and ask more granular questions when you face problems that you cannot find answers to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up some of this code.

1. You don't need to write a function to remove columns, there's already a method to do that with `.drop()`. So delete the function `remove_unwanted_cols(dataset, cols)` and simply change the line:

`df = remove_unwanted_cols(df, ["Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Number_of_Vacancies"])`

to

`df = df.drop(["Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Number_of_Vacancies"], axis=1)`

2. Do you mean to have it send email twice? You have it do it in the `scrape_website()` finction and the `convert_to_dataFrame()` function.
3. If pulling data to construct a dataframe, I usually try to avoid lists, for the exact reason you get the error of some sites have x columns, but the next scrape has and extra one (or not a match in len). Dictionaries are a better way to handle that with the key being the column name, and value the data. So you'll have a list of dictionaries. Each item in the list is a row, and each dictionary corresponds to the value for a column. Then you can get rid of the `convert_to_dataFrame()` function as pandas can do that for you, but we'll leave that in there and you can keep it, or remove it, if you like.
4. If you are using `r''` for your strings, you don't need to character escape the `\`. Either do: `r"F:\AIenv\web_scrapping\jobDesc.xlsx"`, or `"F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx"`

**Code:**

```
import time
from datetime import date
import smtplib

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.utils import formatdate

def scrape_website(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
    subject = url.split('/')
    subject = [x for x in subject if x != ''][-1]
    links = []
    for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
        if a['href'] not in links:
            links.append("https://www.bayt.com" + a['href'])
    
    joineddd = []
    for link in links:
        row = {}
        s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
        job_description = s.find('h2', text='Job Description').find_next('dl')
        data_titles = job_description.find_all('dt')
        for data_title in data_titles:
            dt = '_'.join(data_title.text.split())
            dd = data_title.find_next('dd').text.strip()
            row.update({dt: dd})
                    
        if s.find('h2', text='Preferred Candidate'):
            preferred_candidate = s.find('h2', text='Preferred Candidate').find_next('dl')
            data_titles = preferred_candidate.find_all('dt')
            for data_title in data_titles:
                dt = '_'.join(data_title.text.split())
                dd = data_title.find_next('dd').text.strip()
                row.update({dt: dd})
            
        joineddd.append(row)
            
    print("Web Crawling is Done for  {}".format(url))
    convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd, subject)
    #send_email(subject) #<-- did you want to send here?

def convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd, subject):
    df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd)
    df = df.drop(["Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Number_of_Vacancies"], axis=1)
    df_to_excel = df.to_excel(r"F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx", index = False, header=True)
    send_email(subject)  #<--or do you want to send here??

def send_email(subject):
    '''send email '''
    today = date.today()
    file = 'F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx'
    username='XXXXXXXXXXX'
    password='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    send_from = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    send_to = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    Cc = 'recipient'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Cc'] = Cc
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, This is a test mail {} - {}'.format(today,subject)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    port = '587'
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'vnd.ms-excel')
    part.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='jobs Description--{}'.format(today))
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username, password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to.split(',') + msg['Cc'].split(','), msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')


url_list = ["https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/",
            "https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/head-chef-jobs/",
            "https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-sous-chef-jobs/"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for url in url_list:
        scrape_website(url)
```